# Does flicking your fingers while your palms are on your ears cure tinnitus?

Tags: medical-science, ear

Go90 published a video that was [shared by George Takei on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/georgehtakei/videos/1222243887899002/), garnering many millions of views.

It shows some anecdotal evidence of a handful of long-term [tinnitus sufferers](http://www.tinnitus.asn.au/tinnitus.htm) apparently being cured by a technique found on the Internet. The technique (which seems identical to a Taoist exercise, "[banging the heavenly drum](http://inspireportal.com/the-tao-of-creativity-taoist-tools-to-help-your-writing-and-creative-work/)") involves putting your palms on the side of your head, and flicking your fingers.

While the video warns in the small print to consult a doctor first, it isn't clear what risks are involved (which strikes me as unethical).

Meanwhile, [a summary of a evidence-based clinical review of tinnitus practices from 2014](http://journals.lww.com/thehearingjournal/Fulltext/2014/12000/First_Evidence_Based_Tinnitus_Guideline_Shines.1.aspx) doesn't mention the technique and warns against fads:

> Dr. Jastreboff also expressed skepticism.
>
> “I have seen many claims of ‘highly effective treatment’ over the last 30 years, which turned out to be not true when investigated by independent investigators,” he said.

Are a significant number of tinnitus sufferers helped - even if only temporarily - by this technique?

Comment: Doesn't work for me and I have tinnitus.  At best, it (subjectively) produced a very temporary partial alleviation of symptoms that returned to normal over the period of around one minute.  Not an answer but a partial debunking.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't a partial debunking. That's another anecdote. Maybe it only helps 80% of people. Maybe you did it wrong. Maybe you suffer from a different issue to the one this cures. This needs a controlled study.